# How to get the property value of any control in Silverlight application programmatically using Telerik test framework

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik

I'm trying to come up with a generic way to find the value of a property of a control in Silverlight application given key of a property is specified. 
Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
public class FetchPropertyFromControlCommand
{
     var frameworkElement = broker.Find<FrameworkElement>(ReferenceOfControol);
        var properties = frameworkElement.GetProperties();
        if (properties.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            var output = String.Empty;
            var propertyValue = properties.TryGetValue(propertyName, out output);
        }          
        return false;
}
```

Here frameworkElement.Getproperties lists the properties with key and value. But Value holds the class name and not the actual value what I get  when I  spy the element.  That is `BorderBrush="#FFCBCBCB"`

[[image: Value of property is different]]
Could anyone tell me why GetProperties method doesn't show the actual value what a UI spy shows for a property of a control. Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: What version of VisualStudio are you working with?

Comment: It's visual studio 2015